# When was the nearest star discovered?

Tags: the-sun, amateur-observing, history

When historically did we realize that the Sun is a star, like all the others?

An answer was posted, then the question was put on hold. I would like to answer:
If indeed someone asserted that the Sun was a star 2500 years ago, that is rather humbling. That it took until about 100 years ago for it to be proven is even more humbling!

People level a lot of claims against science and scientists. But if a field of knowledge **takes over 100 generations to prove a true statement**, perhaps they have a right to criticize. So, I think that science needs to do a better job of proving its theories. Either that, or people need to have more common sense, not to recognize something that has been staring billions of people in the face for all time. Perhaps, we should all be a bit more humble about the state of knowledge, even in obvious areas?

Maybe if we had taken the people who proposed this fact, and the concept of atoms, seriously at the time, we would be on our way to *other* stars by now instead of still having only visited that big white thing nearby (forgot the name just now) and that not for the past 40 years.

Comment: About 8 minutes after it started shining... haw haw haw.

Comment: And was it actually discovered by *professionals*, or *amateurs*?

Comment: These are two different questions.

Comment: While your "who discovered the Moon" question was mildly humorous, and was serious enough to possible to keep, please do not continue with this type of questions. This question is not of any value, neither for us nor you. The joke aspect was depleted after the first time.

Comment: Nor a real question, probably intended as a joke, but does not manage to be funny.

Comment: Boy, you people are way too serious. I thought that history of Astronomy would be important. It tends to reduce hubris. So at what point should we not consider history? More than 100 years ago? 10? Maybe the Holocene never happened...

Comment: This question might be better suited to the History of Science and Maths SE: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FJC Already answered there: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/123/when-how-was-it-known-that-our-sun-is-the-same-thing-as-the-night-time-stars

Comment: @nocomprende: If your actual question is "When was the sun recognized as star?", then I'd argue somewhere around 1930, when stars where really understood for the first time, due to progress in nuclear physics.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape A classic Self Inquiry question is: "**What do you know for sure?**" and many people find that there are very very few things that they actually know for sure. Do we understand stars even now? If we don't, do we "know" anything about the Sun, other stars, etc? What if the state of knowledge changes? I guess I wasn't going that far, I was aiming for the idea in the Answer below, which I accepted. But you have a point. A friend once said, "*We can never know anything, really.*" Another friend replied: "*Then I might as well slash my wrists right now.*" Over to you...

Comment: @nocomprende: Well then you've just understood a part of what's wrong with your answer: "until about 100 years ago for it to be proven..." Nothing is ever proven. Even if a judge in a murder case might take a certain amount of evidence as proof, we're not judgdes here, we're detectives.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Maybe it is the concept of knowledge that is suspect then. "*Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be still able to be untrue.*" Or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick google, [This](http://solar-center.stanford.edu/FAQ/Qsunasstar.html) page pops up showing that Anaxagoras was the first documented person to make the link between the sun and stars being the same thing.

Comment: Hypothesised, rather than discovered but close enough.

Comment: The referenced page says "*around AD 1590, Giordano Bruno suggested the same thing, and was burnt at the stake for it.*" So, pretty serious business, I think. Better get it right. It further states: "*finally in the 19th century the distances to stars and other things about them could be measured by various people. Only then was it proved that the Sun is a star.*" Not so long ago, really. I would want to know this, as an Amateur Astronomer. Or was Bruno a Professional? Either way, he was the pig in the breakfast, not the chicken.